# How can I write a Stored Procedure that will reorder numbered data according to a Status Column?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a table that has a numeric column that orders the data, a text field that holds info, and a status column.

```
item_num    item    status
1           Plate   new
2           Cup     continued
3           Fork    new
4           Spoon   revised
```

When an item is updated with a status to "discontinued", I need the list to reorder the item_num to put all items with a "discontinued" status having the highest number, and reorder the other items accordingly. So, if I discontinue the Cup, I need a stored procedure to update the table resulting in this:

```
item_num     item   status
1            Plate  new
2            Fork   new
3            Spoon  revised
4            Cup    discontinued
```

I just need some direction on how to update the data and reorder by status.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server. The item_num is not the Primary Key. The problem I have is that I'm limited on what I can do because I can't make any changes to the table itself, it HAS to be a Stored Procedure, and it HAS to change those numbers. This is for Treatment Plan Goals in an EHR. When the Treatment Plan document generates, it lists the goals by the Goal Number (item_num). So if a user discontinues a goal, the numbering is wrong. The Treatment Plan doesn't show "discontinued" goals. So the Goals go from 1,2,3,4 to 1,2,4 (if I discontinued the 3rd goal).

I am a developer for the front end of an Electronic Health Records system. This Stored Procedure needs to fire when a user clicks a button. This site has been very helpful to me, but is my first post - I know I probably mangled it. Apologies.

Comment: You would use another ordering strategy that was applied then the data was viewed, you would not rewrite the entire item_num column.  Consider a 3rd status table with status_id, status_text, view_order columns where view_order is a number that you can use in an order by query,

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: This sounds like it may be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why do you need to renumber the items.  If the `item_num` is the primary key, this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to achieve this, as long as all rows are `distinct`.  If they are not, you will need a key of some kind to handle the `join`.

First put everything in a temp table and create your new `item_num`

```
SELECT item_num, item, status,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Discontinued' 
                         THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) as 'newnum'
INTO #TEMP
FROM TABLE
```

Then `JOIN` your temp to the main, and replace the old `item_num` with the `newnum`

```
UPDATE ta
SET ta.item_num = t.newnum
FROM table ta
JOIN #temp t on t.item_num = ta.item_num
            AND t.item = ta.item
            AND t.status = ta.status
```